# Weird Indented Block Error At Main Function

Tags: python

My Error

```
  File "controller.py", line 26
    try:
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

And my code:

```
def main():
    config=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open("settings.cfg"),"r")
    for site in config.sections():
       # ipdb.set_trace()
        settings=dict(config.items(site))
        with open('shoes.txt') as fp: <--new code trying to add
            for category, url in csv.reader(fp):  <--new code trying to add
            #ipdb.set_trace()
            #print url,category
            try: <--line 26
```

For some reason I get the error I'm not sure how to fix it can you help me?

I had an old which worked fine:

```
def main():
    config=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open("settings.cfg"),"r")
    for site in config.sections():
       # ipdb.set_trace()
        settings=dict(config.items(site))
        for (url,category) in zip(settings['url'].split(","),settings['category'].split(",")):
            #ipdb.set_trace()
            #print url,category
            try:
... more code
```

Comment: The try must be indented, obviously.

Comment: The old code worked because it had something in the for-loop, namely the try/except block.  The new code does not.

Comment: @iCodez so how can I assign url,category to be used later in the code?

Comment: Actually, they are available.  They are in the variables `url` and `category`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

I rewrote my post now that I know more as to what your problem is...

The reason your old code worked was that it had something in the for-loop, namely the try/except block.  The new code however does not (comments don't count).

To fix your problem, make sure your indentation is good and put something in the for-loop.  Your code probably should look like this:

```
def main():
    config=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open("settings.cfg"),"r")
    for site in config.sections():
        # ipdb.set_trace()
        settings=dict(config.items(site))
        with open('shoes.txt') as fp: <--new code trying to add
            for category, url in csv.reader(fp):  <--new code trying to add
                #ipdb.set_trace()
                #print url,category
                try:
                    ...
```

Comment: Your first example won't work as written because you can't have an empty `for` block; you need at least a `pass`.  (Depending on where the OP wants the `try` indented, this might even be the real problem, who knows?)  [FYI, I wasn't the downvote -- people toss those around too frequently.]

Comment: @iCodez yes I want with try/ecept block in the for loop + keep URL + Category for use

Comment: @iCodez ok so I understood I need to move all the code 4 dots after for command now the code is long anyway to automatically do it? or manually 4 spaces each line?

Comment: @JoJoMe - Well, that depends.  Some IDE's have auto-indenting ability as well as the ability to format code.  If yours doesn't, then yes, you need to do it manually.  Also, 4 spaces is just the Python standard.  You can use any level of indenting (just keep it consistent).

Answer (score 2):

I assume the try should not be part of the for-loop

```
def main():
    config=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open("settings.cfg"),"r")
    for site in config.sections():
       # ipdb.set_trace()
        settings=dict(config.items(site))
        with open('shoes.txt') as fp: <--new code trying to add
            for category, url in csv.reader(fp):  <--new code trying to add
                pass
            #ipdb.set_trace()
            #print url,category
            try: <--line 26
```

Empty blocks are not possible in python, the "for" statement has an empty block. Simply add a "pass" (which does nothing in this case).

Other variation, which seems to match the intended behaviour:

```
def main():
    config=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open("settings.cfg"),"r")
    for site in config.sections():
       # ipdb.set_trace()
        settings=dict(config.items(site))
        with open('shoes.txt') as fp: <--new code trying to add
            for category, url in csv.reader(fp):  <--new code trying to add
                #ipdb.set_trace()
                #print url,category
                try: <--line 26
```

Comment: my old code was for as well. It worked witout "pass" `settings=dict(config.items(site))
        for (url,category) in zip(settings['url'].split(","),settings['category'].split(",")):
            #ipdb.set_trace()
            #print url,category
            try:` what's different here?

Comment: Please add your old code to the question, in a comment the code is not readable.

Comment: Added it please check

Comment: In your original code the "try" is part of the "for". In the updated code, Try and For are on the same level. This is probably an error.